# Distribution of group elements with chosen bits and hardness of discrete log problem

Tags: discrete-logarithm, number-theory

For generator $g$ of order $n$ the group elements $y=g^x$mod $n$ are uniformly distributed because of the modulo operation.

Suppose however that from the original output space $Y$, we only consider those elements $y$ which have some bits "fixed" in their binary representation. For example, for $y = y_1,y_2...y_m$ (where $y_i$ is a bit of the m-bit representation of $y$), consider the output space $Y'$ where all $y \in Y'$ have a static bit $y_i$ in a position $i$ set. Are those $x$ that are valid such that $g^x \in Y'$ (and also the complement set $\bar{Y'}$) still evenly distributed? In other words, is the hardness of the discrete logarithm problem equivalent when considering an output space $Y$ and $Y'$? My intuition says yes because of the modulo operation and the cyclic group, but I am looking for a more convincing answer (with cases $n$ is either prime or power of 2)

I have seen works that talk about "Bit security" (e.g. https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/972639.972642 ) but these talk about the bits of $x$, while I am considering the "inverse" problem for bits of $y$..

Comment: The simple argument, if $n$ is not the power of 2 then no!

Comment: So let's distinguish between the 2 cases (a) if $n$ is prime and (b) if $n$ is power of 2. You say in case (a) the distribution of $x$ where $g^x$ has some chosen prefix is skewed?

Comment: Rephrased the question if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE 20220330: New answer following question clarification; old answer retained to make sense of the comments.

I think that what you are asking is whether the bits of $y$ act as a hard-core function on the inverse of a one-way function (in this case the discrete logarithm function modulo $n$). For background on hard-core functions see for example section 2.4 for [Foundations of Cryptography](https://u.cs.biu.ac.il/%7Elindell/89-856/complete-89-856.pdf)). However, if the inverse of a one-way function is easy to compute (which is true in your case as the exponentiation function can be computed in polynomial time), then there are no hard-core functions.

Cryptographers don't phrase this in terms of uniform distribution, but in terms of discriminators that can be computed in polynomial time and offer non-trivial advantage (see definition 2.4 of the notes). They say that a predicate $b(y)$ is hard-core for $f$ if for all polynomial time discriminators we have
$$\mathbb P(A(f(U_n)),1^n)=b(U_n)<1/2+1/p(n).$$
In your case $f$ is the function $y=g^x\mod n\mapsto x$ and your function $b$ is the $i$th bit of $y=g^x\mod n$. However, I have the counterexample discriminator $A(z,1^n)$ which is to compute $g^z\mod n$ (in polynomial time) and look at the $i$th bit. This discriminates answers with probability 1 because with first argument $f(y)=x$ it returns $b(y)$.

In other words there is a computationally verifiable lack of uniformity because I can quickly test $x$ values to see whether or not they produce output that lies in $Y'$.

Old answer.

Yes. Let $|Y'|=M$ and let $z$ be any element of $Y'$ then Bayes' theorem tells us that
$$\mathbb P(g^x\mod n=z|g^x\mod n\in Y')=\frac{\mathbb P(g^x\mod n=z)\mathbb P(g^x\mod n\in Y'|g^c\mod n=z)}{\mathbb P(g^x\mod n\in Y')}.$$
We now note that $\mathbb P(g^x\mod n=z)=1/\phi(n)$ (by the uniformity noted in the question), $\mathbb P(g^x\mod n\in Y'|g^c\mod n=z)=1$ and that $\mathbb P(g^x\mod n\in Y')=M/\phi(n)$ (again by the uniformity in the question). Thus
$$\mathbb P(g^x\mod n=z|g^x\mod n\in Y')=1/M$$
for all $z\in Y'$ which describes a uniform distribution.

Comment: Thanks, but does the Bayes approach really capture the distribution of $x$? I.e. those $x$ that are "valid" such that $g^x \in Y'$ could be potentially skewed in terms of the whole space $Y$? E.g. maybe for "fixing" some bit $y_b$, those $x$ could potentially have the probability for one of its bits to be equal to 0 to be greater than 1/2?

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow your comment. If you are asking "Is it possible to construct a conditional probability distribution where Bayes' theorem does not apply?" Then the answer is "No". Also note that although the values of $g^x$ are uniformly distributed, the bits are not e.g. for a $B$-bit $p$ the MSB is 0 with probability $(2^{B-1}-1)/(p-1)$ and 1 with probability $(p-2^{B-1})/2$.

Comment: So I am asking about the distribution of $x$, not $g^x$. And my question is if the distribution of $x$ (i.e. the probability that some bit of $x$ is 0 or 1) somehow changes if I "fix" some bit in the representation of $y = g^x$. I don't see how the fact that P = $1/M$ for all $z \in Y'$ show that $x$ are still uniformly distributed over the *original* output space $Y$..

Comment: I think that I now understand your question and have amended my answer.

Comment: So the question is if a specific bit of output $y$ reveals some information about any bit of preimage $x$. Therefore, I think the function $b$ should be *any* bit of $x$ (**not** $y$), and if the discriminator with that bit of $y$ set, can predict with probability greater than 1/2 any bit of $x$ (awarded bounty because it expires)

Comment: If we restrict ourselves to single bit linear approximations as you describe, then any mutual information between a single bit of $y$ and a single bit of $x$ works both ways with both predicates being easy to compute. Other than the bias on bits due to the modulus, any further information would be a hard predicate on the bits of the discrete logarithm which we do not believe exists.